# How do i connect two types in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, schema, gatsby

So I have two types in GraphQL:

> article.mdx

```
---
title: "Post n.1"
category: "Category"
---

Post Content
```

> categories.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Category",
    "description": "This is a description",
    "order": 1
  }
]
```

I want to query my post type in order to have this kind of result:

```
{
 "node": {
   "title": Post n.1
   "category": {
     "name": "Category",
     "description": "This is a description",
     "order": 1
   }
 }
}
```

How can i do this? I'm currently using GatsbyJS! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

its pretty easy as you know you should use `gatsby-transformer-remark` to read md files , so for the json files you should use `gatsby-transformer-json` , add it in the `gatsby-config.js` file under plugins. then you need to query your data , unfortunatly i realy dont think you can combile two files to get data as you ask , but you can try this

first in gatsby-node.js file you need to reference the variables you gonna use for filter the query data , pass those fields in to the `context`

```
exports.createPages = async function({ actions, graphql }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.fields.slug
    actions.createPage({
      path: slug,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/article.js`),
      context: { category: category},
    })
  })
}
```

then in your page query you can accesss the filterd query by this read more in [Creating Pages from Data Pro grammatically](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/)

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
        query MyQuery($category: String!) {
          allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {category: {eq: $category}}}) {
            edges {
              node {
                frontmatter {
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
          allDataJson(filter: {name: {eq: $category}}) {
            edges {
              node {
                nodes {
                  name,
                  description,
                  order
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }`
```

then access you can access the your data by `const {allMarkdownRemark , allDataJson} = data`

then combine those two data as you prefer

```
const item = {node : { title: allMarkdownRemark.edges.node[0].frontmatter }};
item.node.category = allDataJson.edges.node[0].nodes
```

note this was assuming that edges.node is an array so we need to exact the 1st element of your data by node[0] , please check whether this method is working .

and the structure for the json data was

```
{ "nodes": [ {
     "name": "Category",
     "description": "This is a description",
     "order": 1
      } 
   ]
}
```